# List of duplicate leads in dynamics 365

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

There is a requirement where i have to list the duplicate leads in a separate view in dynamics 365. Out of the box that is not possible.
How do i achieve this using code
Kindly advise
Best Regards

Comment: what is your criteria for duplicate lead? Lead Guid cannot be duplicate. Where do you wish to show this view? Do you wish to create html page and show table grid as view?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response AnkUser. i would like to list the duplicate lead record based on email in leads view. They want to see the list of duplicate leads based on email anywhere within CRM. Please guide

Comment: Could anybody please advise

Comment: You have to probably show your attempt and from there ask for help here